# prometheus can't load rule_files

Tags: prometheus

> prometheus, version 2.7.2 (branch: HEAD, revision: 82f98c8) 
>   build user: root@ab86c672c33a 
>   build date: 20190302-14:57:04 
>   go version:go1.11.5

All program in docker.
prometheus.yml

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     10s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 10s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).
# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets: ['192.168.0.238:9093']

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"
  - "/docker/prometheus/sd_config/alert_rules/alertmanager_rules.yml"
```

alertmanager_rules.yml

```
groups:
 - name: alert-name
   rules:
   - alert: InstanceDown # 告警名称
     expr: up == 0 # 告警的判定条件，参考Prometheus高级查询来设定
     for: 2m # 满足告警条件持续时间多久后，才会发送告警
     labels: #标签项
       team: node
     annotations: # 解析项，详细解释告警信息
       summary: "{{$labels.instance}}: has been down"
       description: "{{$labels.instance}}: job {{$labels.job}} has been down "
       value: {{$value}}
```

[prometheus config](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6670377/54264911-21318e80-45af-11e9-97ab-be41aaedeb10.png) 
[alertmanager_rules file](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6670377/54264922-28f13300-45af-11e9-9688-1a0477d6da70.png)

but I can see any rules in web. 
http://192.168.0.10:9090/alerts 
I get "No alerting rules defined "
[web alert image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6670377/54264965-3efef380-45af-11e9-8f0f-2d42377babbe.png)

http://192.168.0.10:9090/rules 
I get "No rules defined " 
[web rules image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6670377/54264977-445c3e00-45af-11e9-8a08-4810b3613a0f.png)

In alertmanager web 
http://192.168.0.238:9093/#/alerts 
I get "No alerts found"

Comment: in alertmanager_rules.yml -------     value: {{$value}}    must be    value: "{{$value}}"

Comment: did you find how to slove the issue ?

Comment: my format is error, value: {{$value}} must be value: "{{$value}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value: {{$value}} must be value: "{{$value}}"